# how find next row of button clicked in td?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have table and for every row i have another row that is `dispaly:none`.
i want when i clicked `span` in `td` of visible `row` next `row` be visible.

i tried :-

```
$('span').click(function()
            $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').css('display','block')
        })
```

this switch display to block but the tr not displayed correctly as when it's display is block by default.
when i try this the next row width is as first column of currnet tr. whats the problem?

```
 <tr>
    <td style="width:40px"></td>
    <td><span>show</span></td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
  <tr "style=display:none">
    <td colspan="4" >
        <h5>پاسخ دادن</h5>
        <textarea style="width:100%;"></textarea>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: `"style=display:none"`  That is wrong, guessing typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy solution is to set the display to blank like

```js
$('span').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').css('display', '');//or set it as table-row which is the default display for tr
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:40px"></td>
    <td><span>show</span></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none">
    <td colspan="3">
      <h5>پاسخ دادن</h5>
      <textarea style="width:100%;"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also it is not advisable to use block elements like h5 inside td. Use span and style it

Comment: @MarikkaniChelladurai Got a source to back that up?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `parent` selector in jquery

```
$('span').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').next('tr').show();
    });
```

> refer [**HERE**](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Comment: Your code had a bracket missing that makes it a major difference for a code with error and one without error

Comment: yes, thank for your effort. the bracket missing while copy pasting.

Comment: its ok if my answer wasnt helpful